# Кириллица fgets() PHP

Tags: php, потоки-данных, консоль

Не могу разобраться с кодировкой. Данная функция выполняется, и просит запрос ввода. При вводе русских символов происходит следующие... PHP 7.0, запущен в модуле CLI. В итоге fgets возвращает пустую строку размер в количество символов, но не как не русские символы. С английскими символами, все работает отлично. Перепробовал многое, попрошу помощи.

```
function queryline($prompt = '')//наша функция запроса ввода
{
    echo $prompt;
    $str = fgets(STDIN);
    return iconv('ASCII', 'UTF-8', $str);
}
```

Comment: Вот именно, я пробил что за кодировка, и оказалось что оно пишет ASCII, вот и перевожу ASCII в UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, а вы уверены, что вывод UTF-8 в терминал в вашем конкретном случае отобразится корректно? Попробуйте сначала убедиться, что ваш php-файл сохранен в UTF-8, и сделать просто вывод `echo 'русский текст';`. Если отобразится корректно - тогда идем далее.

Во-вторых, попробуйте [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) вместо iconv, эта функция должна более корректно определять входящую кодировку. Но это тоже не панацея, т.к. не совсем понятно, в какой кодировке данные приходят с терминала.

Если и это не поможет - попробуйте iconv, но с предварительным явным определением входящей кодировки с помощью [mb_detect_encoding](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-detect-encoding.php).

Comment: Вот именно, я пробил что за кодировка, и оказалось что оно пишет ASCII, вот и перевожу ASCII в UTF-8.

Comment: не понял, что "оно" и куда "пишет"?

Comment: Под "оно" я определяю ` mb_convert_encoding` а под "пишет", я имею ввиду что возвращает выше описанная функция.

Comment: так, тогда я запутался... давайте по-шагам... `echo(mb_detect_encoding($str));` - что выводит в терминал?  (именно ДЕТЕКТ, а не конверт)

Comment: далее, что покажет `echo (mb_detect_encoding('русский текст'));` ? И что получится, если `echo 'русский текст';`?

Comment: detect... Выводит ASCII как я уже и говорил. echo у меня работает нормально, это все проверено не один раз. Дело именно в потоке. detect в этом случае когда мы вводим статический текст, выводит не ASCII а UTF-8.

Comment: ну, мне-то отсюда не видно, что проверено один раз, а что не один :)  Так, из того, что вы написали (если я правильно понял), дело именно во *входном* потоке (*если вы именно это имели в виду под "именно в потоке" - то, похоже, вы правы*). В таком случае, копать надо за пределами php-скрипта. Проверяем  настройки кодировки терминала (putty, я полагаю?), установоки локалей shell и установку кодировки default_charset в php.ini. Как именно - тут уж Гугл подробнее расскажет, но для поиска я бы выбирал именно эти три направления.

Comment: Спасибо, но это pytty, это CLI запущенный из командой строки Windows 10. Последую вашем советам. Возможно поможет.

Comment: default_charset равен UTF-8, кодировка командой строки UTF-8. Расскажите подробнее про локали, может в этом дело...

Comment: Выяснилось еще кое-что, английские символы, в потоке ввода, идут тоже в ASCII но оторбражаются коректно, значит дело в кодировке потока ввода.