# PHP STDIN: чтение кириллицы из командной строки

Tags: php, кодировка, потоки-данных, командная-строка

Пишу в целях самообучения чат на php в консоли windows. Столкнулся со следующим: при чтении из потока ввода командной строки win10 и последующем выводе через echo обратно в командную строку все символы кириллицы подменяются пустыми местами (даже не крокозябрами).

[Тема уже ранее встречалась](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/725274/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-fgets-php) на stackOverflow. Симптомы один - в - один, но советы из комментариев мне не помогли и однозначного решения предложено не было.

В ходе работы с этой граблЁй написал небольшой скрипт для тестирования:

```
<?php
echo "Введите строку для чтения-вывода: ";
$string = stream_get_line(STDIN, 255, PHP_EOL);

$zeroString = "english-русский-english";
echo "-------------------------------------" . PHP_EOL;
echo "Кодировка контрольной строки: " . mb_detect_encoding($zeroString) . PHP_EOL;
echo "Контрольная строка на выходе: " . $zeroString . PHP_EOL;
echo "-------------------------------------" . PHP_EOL;
echo "Кодировка введенной строки: " . mb_detect_encoding($string) . PHP_EOL;
echo "Введенная строка после обработки: " . $string . PHP_EOL;
```

Вывод данного кода представил ниже и скриншотом приложил на всякий случай

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\Algorythms>php t1.php
Введите строку для чтения-вывода: english-русский-english
-------------------------------------
Кодировка контрольной строки: UTF-8
Контрольная строка на выходе: english-русский-english
-------------------------------------
Кодировка введенной строки: ASCII
Введенная строка после обработки: english-       -english
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Было дело, да. Так и не решил на самом деле.